# iPhone X Safe Layout Area in Objective-C App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an app writted in Objectice-c without storyboard & Autolayout.

I am facing issue in iPhone X (Please see below)

**---iPhone X---**

[image: iPhone X]

**---iPhone SE---**

[image]

Below is the code for Bold title what I have written

```
_topHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-60, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)* 0.2)];

   _topHeaderLabel.text = @"Please select bank account you want to link";
   _topHeaderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

I can see UI is perfect in all iPhone devices except iPhone X. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. I can't apply auto layout as the app is already written.

Any Idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: Did you inset everything by `safeAreaInsets` ?

Comment: @Brandon no I did not.

Comment: Just know that by adding black over that text, doesn't stop us from finding what's below. If it's sensitive information, remove it from the post (and ask imgur to take down that image): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184099/secure-way-of-masking-out-sensitive-information-in-screenshots?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem  in your height it must be

```
_topHeaderLabel.sizeToFit()
```

plus check this if detect device is X -> `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top`
Try this in IPhoneX , top inset  in IPhoneX is 44 but you're setting 20 , if you use navigatioBar it'll be 88

```
UILabel*topHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,self.view.safeAreaInsets.top, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-60, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)* 0.2)];
```